# Problems with stdout

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, monitor, mode

I'm designing a shell bash script. It has a lot of functions and one of them is to detect if a network card is in monitor mode. Not sure if there is a "pro" method to do that. My rudimentary method is working but has a problem. Is the next function:

```
function monitor() {

    WIFI="wlan0" #hardcoded wlan0 for the example
    mode=`iwconfig $WIFI|cut -d ' ' -f 6`

    if [[ $mode == "Mode:Monitor" ]]; then
        echo "Your interface $WIFI is in monitor mode already"
        return
    fi
    #Here is the rest of the function... not relevant
}
```

The problem is printing in screen the stdout of the command and I don't want anything printed in screen. So the first I thought is to redirect the stdout to /dev/null doing this:

```
mode=`iwconfig $WIFI|cut -d ' ' -f 6 > /dev/null 2>&1`
```

But if I do that, it stop to working... I think because it needs the stdout to pipe one command to other to work.

If I select an already monitor mode card everything is ok. The problem is if the network interface is not in monitor mode (eth0 for example), it prints this:

eth0      no wireless extensions.

What can I do to use the stdout for the pipe and prevent printing anything in screen?

Thank you in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: stdout of `iwconfig` is not going to your tty, but stderr is.  Try `mode=$(iwconfig 2> /dev/null $WIFI|cut -d ' ' -f 6)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silence `stderr` of your `iwconfig` command (using `2> /dev/null` redirection):

```
iwconfig $WIFI 2> /dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f 6
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not include `> /dev/null` in your command substitution**, as it will prevent capturing *anything* in variable `mode`.

If your intent is to **capture stdout and *silence* stderr** in variable `$mode`:

```
mode=`iwconfig "$WIFI" 2>/dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f 6 `
```

If your intent is to **capture *both* stdout and stderr**, as your solution attempt suggests:

```
mode=`iwconfig "$WIFI" 2>&1 | cut -d ' ' -f 6 `
```

Note: As @nsilent22 points out in a comment and in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35661809/45375), **placement of `2/dev/null`  or `2>&1` is crucial** here: it is `iwconfig` that potentially produces stderr output, so the redirection must be applied to *it*, not to `cut`.

Generally, if you wanted to **apply a redirection to a pipeline *as a whole***, you can **use *command grouping***; e.g.:

```
mode=`{ iwconfig "$WIFI" | cut -d ' ' -f 6; } 2>/dev/null`
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers... I tried both: mode=$(iwconfig 2> /dev/null $WIFI|cut -d ' ' -f 6) and mode=$(iwconfig "$WIFI" |cut -d ' ' -f 6 2>&1)... the same result. It prints "eth0      no wireless extensions." when a non monitor iface is used. :/

Comment: You put the redirection at a wrong place. You don't need to redirect `stderr` of the `cut` command, but `iwconfig`